# How do I disable text characters from being entered in Kendo DatePicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, datepicker

I am using KendoDatePicker, and I do not know how to not allow the user to enter alphabetical characters.

How do I do it?

```
$("#DatePicker").kendoDatePicker({
        start: "year",
        depth: "date",
        format: "MM/dd/yyyy",
        parseFormats: ["MM dd yyyy", "M-d-yy", "M/d/yy", "M/d/yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "M d yy"]
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this way?

```
$('#DatePicker').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

or

```
$("#DatePicker").attr("readonly","readonly");
```